# Рекурсивное наследование в дженериках

Tags: c#, ооп

Есть класс `Game`. Его реализация не важна, можно опустить её до следующего вида:

```
public class Game {}
```

Есть интерфейс `IGamePiece`:

```
public interface IGamePiece<TGame, TMove>
    where TGame : Game
    where TMove : GameMove<TGame, IGamePiece<TGame, TMove>>
{
    TMove[] GetAvailableMoves(TGame game);
}
```

и класс `GameMove`:

```
public class GameMove<TGame, TPiece>
    where TGame : Game
    where TPiece : class, IGamePiece<TGame, GameMove<TGame, TPiece>>
{
    // public GameBoardSquareCoordinates EndCoordinates { get; }
    public TPiece Piece { get; }
}
```

Из-за рекурсии возникает ошибки и код не компилируется. Ошибки:

1. `The type 'IGamePiece<TGame,TMove>' cannot be used as type parameter 'TPiece' in the generic type or method 'GameMove<TGame,TPiece>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'IGamePiece<TGame,TMove>' to 'IGamePiece<TGame,GameMove<TGame,IGamePiece<TGame,TMove>>>'`
2. `The type 'GameMove<TGame,TPiece>' cannot be used as type parameter 'TMove' in the generic type or method 'IGamePiece<TGame,TMove>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'GameMove<TGame,TPiece>' to 'GameMove<TGame,IGamePiece<TGame,GameMove<TGame,TPiece>>>'`

Я пытаюсь добиться того, чтобы:

1. У интерфейса `IGamePiece` можно было указывать тип `TMove` - наследника `GameMove`
2. У класса `GameMove` можно было указывать тип `TPiece` - наследника `IGamePiece`.

Comment: Ошибка какая? Скопируйте ее из окна вывода.

Comment: @こきん указал ошибки

Comment: Убирайте рекурсию, это у вас какая-то ошибка в проектировании структуры программы. КусокИгры, что бы это не значило может зависеть от ходов, но от обратной зависимости стоит избавляться.

Comment: не "КусокИгры" а "Игровая фишка"

Comment: Ваш пример сводится к рекурсивному наследованию, а это запрещено в c#.